# Cake php changes url domain to localhost

Tags: cakephp

I have a cakephp app that I have to move to a new site. I am running the host of an IP without a domain name. My application after I login the user redirects to a localhost address. There is obviously nothing there, since the installation is on a remote machine. Anyone has any suggestions what I should look for?

Comment: This sounds like a webserver configuration issue to me. Which web server are you using? Also, you should check your `app/Config/core.php` to ensure that the path isn't hardcoded for some reason. Also worth checking `app/Config/routes.php`, oh and clear your cache from `app/tmp`

Comment: You are right, I had the routes set wrong in core.php.